# help with iphone session login

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I see in many apps that you only need to login to an app once and then the next time you open the app, you don't need to input the username and password again. How can I do this with the help of SFHFKeychainUtils?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much answered your question already. You can store credentials in the application's Keychain using the SFHFKeychainUtils wrapper. When the application loads, it checks to see if there is a password. If not, prompt the user to login and store the username & password accordingly.

```
// Application Loads... 

NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *username = [standardDefaults stringForKey:@"kApplicationUserNameKey"];

if (username) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *password = [SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:username andServiceName:@"com.company.app" error:&error];

    // Check password...
} else {
    // No username. Prompt the user to enter username & password and store it
    username = @"userEnteredUsername";
    NSString *password = @"userEnteredPassword";

    [standardDefaults setString:username forKey:@"kApplicationUserName"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL storeResult = [SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:username andPassword:password forServiceName:@"com.company.app" updateExisting:YES error:&error];
}
```

This is obviously incomplete and not organized in the appropriate fashion but you should be able to understand the basic flow.

Comment: the issue is that SFHF needs a username in order to check whether a password exists or not with that username... so how do I get around this

Comment: You could use a constant username.

Also, for future reference, make it clear what exactly you're having problems with. In your original post you refer to a username / password scheme.

Comment: yes, actually it is right.. in a login page we always see a username and password right... so in this case, you're suggesting to hardcode the username?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're needing now... Can you please make what you're having trouble with clear? With SFHFKeychainUtils you can store a username & password. If your application is going to use usernames in any manner, they should be stored there. If not, and there will just be a password entry, use a constant username.

Comment: Ok..imagine you launch an app the first time, you have two textfield, username and password, the constant value is null. I enter these two fields, and store the username/password in the keychain. Next time I launch the app, the code needs to check the constant value (what you refer as username here).. which is null. You said use a constant. If this is the case then the very first time the app is launched by a user.. it needs to already know what his/her username is?

Comment: Ah! I get what you're describing now. You can save the username in `NSUserDefaults` and use that to access the credentials in the keychain. I will update my original answer with sample code.

Comment: there isn't any setString for the NSUserDefaults, there is a setValue.. did you mean that?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. The joys of writing code without Xcode installed :-). You should be able to call `setObject:forKey`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaults for that purpose.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Next time user opens your app, you can simply get this info:

```
NSString *username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"username"];
NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"password"];
```

Comment: Credentials shouldn't be stored in `NSUserDefaults`; they should be stored in a secure location such as the Keychain.

Comment: Good to know, just found an article that says user defaults are stored open text in plist file, which is synced when you perform backups. Thanks Dylan.