# storing username and password in session iphone

Tags: iphone, session

I want to store username and password in a session , if a user login successfully then he will be directed to the welcome screen where a logout button is exist.

now if user close the application without log out the account and restart the app the he must be directed to the welcome screen skipping the login screen. and if user restart the app after logout then he must enter the username and password to come on welcome screen. help me out. i am new to iphone.

Comment: You can store the value into the NSUserDefaults Class

Comment: You can use NSUserDefaults or Plist to save username password.

Answer (score 2):

you may store the username and password in User Defaults or in Keychain (if want to keep it secure ). So on loading the app if you find username and password stored in Userdefaults , you may directly login to welcome screen and if not stored then show the login screen...

see this is the same as you want  [help with iphone session login](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5919328/1030951)

Answer (score 1):

you can store whole array in the Userdefault, UserDefault is a one type of session in the iPhone...

here you can store any value or array in the UserDefaul..

In AppDelegate.h file just declare variable...

```
NSUserDefaults  *userDefaults;
```

here it not compulsory to global declare this userDefault, you can direct use the userdefault where you want

after...

In AppDelegate.m Fille in applicationDidFinishLonching: Method or anywhere which you want to store username and pssword

```
userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefault setObject:yourName forKey:@"UserName"];
[userDefault setObject:yourPassword forKey:@"Password"];
[userDefault synchronize];
```

after that when you want get data from this UserDefaults Use Bellow Code...

```
NSString *userName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UserName"];
NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Password"];
```

i hope this helpful to you...

:)

Comment: Hello Paras. Can we use Keychain access instead of NSUserDefaults? Which one is better?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is better with my opinion.. i used that and its very easy to use..